# How can I get my app to run on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, cluster-computing

I have created a console application in C# using .NET 2.0. I have tested the application on the 32 and 64 bit versions of Windows Server 2003 and it is working properly. When I tried to run the application on Windows Server 2008, but it doesn't work. Later, someone told me to turn off UAC (User Access Control and Data Execution Prevention Paths) and it worked. Now my application fails on Cluster for Windows 2008. What can I do to fix this, along with what I have already done?

Comment: Please provide some detail about the failure.

Comment: It's definitely not a good practice to disable the DEPP on a server, the UAC for a server isn't very important IMO since the UAC functionality is much more geared to desktops than needed in a server environment.

Answer (score 0):

Since is tagged sql-server I assume by running your application on cluster you really mean connect your application to a clustered instance of SQL Server. To connect to a cluster you need to specify the clustered instance resource name in the connection string, not the computer name of any of the nodes in the cluster.